# PHPのエラー「指定されたモジュールが見つかりません。」について

Tags: php, windows

PHPでサーバにログインしてファイル送信を行いたいのですが、ssh2_connect の呼び出しで `C:\xampp\php\ext\php_ssh2.dll` は存在しているのですが、下記のエラーメッセージが表示されます。
原因が分からないのですが分かる方がいらっしゃいましたら返答をお願い致します。

```
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_ssh2.dll'
 - 指定されたモジュールが見つかりません。
```

php.ini には以下を設定しています。

```ini
extension=php_ssh2.dll
```

環境：xampp+PHP7.1

Comment: 32bit 版と 64bit 版を混ぜてインストールしちゃっているとか `php_ssh2.dll` が 32bit 版で xampp が 64bit 版とか、その逆とか。そういうのを調べるツールがあれば自分で調べるもよし、なければ一式全部（削除後に）再インストールのほうが手早いかも。

Comment: ありがとうございます！
以下のサイトからダウンロードしたphp_ssh2.dllを「Thread Safe (TS) x86」のものに変更したらうまくいきました。
https://pecl.php.net/package/ssh2/1.2/windows

Comment: 解決した場合にはコメント欄で終わらせず、ぜひ個別の回答として投稿してみてください。